# Querying a complex doc in elasticsearch Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I am new in the world of elasticsearch.

We are dealing in our project with complex docs that we store in our elasticsearch database.

This is a part of our doc:

```
{
   "AAA":[
      {
         "SSS":{
            "Description":{
               "Detail":[
                  {
                     "Name":"A9",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A8",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A7",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A6",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A5",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A4",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A3",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A2",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"A1",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want a query that return the " Infos" & "Name" fields specific to `"Name":"A1"` for example.I don't want to display all the table of JSON Object Detail but just the Object which `"Name":"A1"`.
In other terms I want a query that return this part of the doc:

```
{
   "AAA":[
      {
         "SSS":{
            "Description":{
               "Detail":[
                  {
                     "Name":"A1",
                     "Infos":"...."
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using elasticsearch 5.4
This is the mapping I am using:

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "-----":{
         "properties":{
            "AAA":{
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{
                  "SSS":{
                     "properties":{
                        "Description":{
                           "properties":{
                              "Detail":{
                                 "type":"nested",
                                 "properties":{
                                    "Infos":{
                                       "type":"keyword"
                                    },
                                    "Name":{
                                       "type":"keyword"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

These are two queries I tried but it didn't work:

```
  GET /******/******/_search
{
  "_source":["AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name","AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"],
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name",
            "query" : "A1"

        }
    }
}


GET /******/******/_search
{
  "_source":["AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name","AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"],

      "filter": [
        { "term":  { "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name": "A1" }}

      ]
}
```

I am trying all the day and it didn't work for me.
Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `AAA.SSS.Detail` field is probably not nested. You should read this and you'll get an idea how to make it work: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: This is the mapping that I am using:                                                                                    "mappings": {
"-----": {
"properties": {
 
"AAA": {
"type": "nested", 

"properties": {

"SSS": { 
"properties": {

"Description": {
"properties": {
"Detail":  { 
"type": "nested" ,
"properties": {
"Infos": { "type": "keyword" },
"Name":  { "type": "keyword" },
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: Can you show what queries you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried these two queries:                                                                                                     GET /******/******/_search{
  "_source":["AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name","AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"],
    "query": {"query_string" : { "default_field" :"AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name",
            "query" : "A1"         
        }
    }
}
GET /******/******/_search
{
  "_source":["AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name","AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"],
      "filter": [
        { "term":  { "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name": "A1" }}  
      ]
}

Comment: Please update your question with them, it'll be more legible.

Comment: Done thanks for yr interest

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353931/elasticsearch-kibana-alerting-x-pack-for-energy-monitoring-system

Answer (score 0):

The `query_string` query doesn't work yet with `nested` data. You need to create a [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) with a `term` query in it. This should get you going:

```
GET /******/******/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "AAA",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name": "A1"
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name",
                "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yr response: I tried the query but it gieves me this error:                    
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "[inner_hits] _source doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[inner_hits] _source doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: The query is giving me all the AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name not just AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name which is  equal to "A1"

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that works with my example:

```
    POST index/type/_search
 {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name": "A1"
          }
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "_source": {
              "includes":["AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Name","AAA.SSS.Description.Detail.Infos"]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the result:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.89712,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AV2NxhX8nWBA4r3kkKAM",
        "_score": 1.89712,
        "_source": {
          "AAA": [
            {
              "SSS": {
                "Description": {
                  "Detail": [
                    {
                      "Name": "A9",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A8",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A7",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A6",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A5",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A4",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A3",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A2",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "A1",
                      "Infos": "...."
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "AAA.SSS.Description.Detail": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.89712,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "AAA",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "SSS.Description.Detail",
                      "offset": 8
                    }
                  },
                  "_score": 1.89712,
                  "_source": {
                    "AAA": {
                      "SSS.Description.Detail": {
                        "Infos": "....",
                        "Name": "A1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```